# Confused in what to use - Preferences or SQLite  or File?

Tags: android, caching, android-listview

I have a list view contains 100+ rows. every time the user opens the app it load all the data from http. And i want to cache that data so that if to open that activity it should get it from the cache not from the http every time.

also i am thinking add some flag to clear out the cache (if for some reason if my url changes it should not read fro cache version rather get the latest urls

I am not sure what to use cache inside the sd card vs sqllite.

my listview contains the url, artist, name,  .... these are all reference something like this:

```
<song>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Someone Like You</title>
    <artist>Adele</artist>
    <duration>4:47</duration>
    <plays>1662</plays>
    <songs_url>http://website/music/someonelikeyou.mp3</songs_url>
    <thumb_url>http://website/music/images/adele.png</thumb_url>
</song>
```

here is the code that reads from http:

```
// Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
// @param url string
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite of course. It was done for holding such king of information. It is fast and easie to select filtered information. 
For images (like thumbs) use cache folder: `context.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: are you taking about storing the url reference in the SQLite correct? or storing the mp3 and other images in the SQLite ? just wanted to make sure you understand my question and we are on same page

Comment: Put all your "light" information (like text) inside data base and "heavy" information (like images and mp3) to SD card.

Comment: i have 100+ (as i said in my question) audio .....currently i am streaming and if i go ahead and put all the audio in the sd card and i am sure it will take lot of space... is this is the only way to go?, i store the light information like references in the sqllite so that my app dont need to go online to read the xml and store in the ArrayList... thought?

Comment: "i store the light information like references in the sqllite so that my app dont need to go online to read the xml and store in the ArrayList" - this is ok

Comment: i can also store in the strings.xml as an arraylist file rite? so whats the main benefit for having in sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 main cases:

1. Load XML from internet.
2. Compare date stamp to you previously saved XML in cache folder (if exist)
3. Delete old XML if update is needed and save new XML to cache folder.
4. Parse XML and display data to user.
5. Load XML from internet
6. Compare date stamp
7. If update is needed update DB
8. Display data to user.

Save and deleting XML file is "harder" operation than clearing data base.
You can clear specific items from data base. / You cant do it with XML.
You can query filtered data from data base. / You cant do it with XML (only after parsing).
You can put into data base additionall columns like image cache folder path etc.
Getting and saving data to data base is faster and more elegant way.

Comment: `Compare date stamp to you previously saved XML in cache folder (if exist)` how would i do that?

Comment: I think best way is to use SharedPref

Comment: why do you think its best way to use sharepref?